# How can a struct with a single object field be faster than a raw object?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a `struct` that holds a single `object` field to make working with the object easier. I wanted to test the performance (I expected some degradation), but I get very surprising results. **The version with the `struct` actually is faster:**

> Without box: 8.08 s
>
> With box: 7.76 s

**How is this possible?**

Below is the complete test code to reproduce the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication68
{
    partial class Program
    {
        private const int Iterations = 100000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Force JIT compilation.

            TimeWithoutBox(new MyObject());
            TimeWithoutBox(7);
            TimeBox(new MyObject());
            TimeBox(7);

            // The tests.

            var withoutBox = new TimeSpan();
            var box = new TimeSpan();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                withoutBox += TimeWithoutBox(new MyObject());
                withoutBox += TimeWithoutBox(7);
                box += TimeBox(new MyObject());
                box += TimeBox(7);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Without box: " + withoutBox);
            Console.WriteLine("With box: " + box);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static TimeSpan TimeBox(object value)
        {
            var box = new MyBox(value);

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                TestBox(box);
            }

            return stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }

        private static TimeSpan TimeWithoutBox(object value)
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                TestWithoutBox(value);
            }

            return stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void TestBox(MyBox box)
        {
            if (box.IsDouble)
                TakeDouble((double)box.Value);
            else if (box.IsObject)
                TakeObject((MyObject)box.Value);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void TestWithoutBox(object box)
        {
            if (box.GetType() == typeof(double))
                TakeDouble((double)box);
            else if (box.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
                TakeObject((MyObject)box);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void TakeDouble(double value)
        {
            // Empty method to force consuming the cast.
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void TakeObject(MyObject value)
        {
            // Empty method to force consuming the cast.
        }
    }

    struct MyBox
    {
        private readonly object _value;

        public object Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        public MyBox(object value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public bool IsDouble
        {
            get { return _value.GetType() == typeof(double); }
        }

        public bool IsObject
        {
            get { return _value.GetType() == typeof(MyObject); }
        }
    }

    class MyObject
    {
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've changed the `IsDouble` and `IsObject` tests to have the same statements as the other test. I've re-executed the application and the resulting times are exactly the same.

**EDIT2:**

This code was tested using a **Release** build compiling at **32-bit without** the debugger attached; .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. Compiling it against 64-bit gives drastically different results; on my machine:

> Without box: 8.23 s
>
> With box: 16.99 s

Comment: 32ms difference over 100million iterations?  who cares.

Comment: How do you know that you're not indirectly testing the efficiency of  `IsDouble`, `IsObject`, `GetType()` and `typeof()`?

Comment: which visual studio version have you used? have you repeated the tests? and have you tried different builds --- release / debug ? .... and a little bit a curiosity ..... and have you tried mono in addition?

Comment: @Dan-o: You're absolutely right, but I think this is just very strange and I'm trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips: You are right, but the point is that it shouldn't matter. The whole thing is inlined and in the end the way that the `double` and `JsObject` is tested is the same. Both tests use `GetType()`.

Comment: @mnemonic: I'm using VS 2010 and I have done many repeating tests. One example is that I've put an `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)` around the whole thing, and this gives the same results. The only build version I'm testing is release **without** the debugger attached (`Ctrl+F5`) (the JIT compiler seems to generate different code depending on whether you start with the debugger attached).

Comment: @Dan-o: BTW it's not 32ms, it's 320ms. 4% difference is in my opinion huge. The whole reason I'm doing these tests is that I'm doing very low level performance optimizations, and this is makes huge difference for me.

Comment: Correction; I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied the exact code, ran it Release without debugger (both important!) and on x64. Results:

```
Without box: 00:00:07.9650541
With box: 00:00:16.0958162
```

Changing the test to:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private static void TestBox(MyBox box)
    {
        if (box.Value.GetType() == typeof(double))
            TakeDouble((double)box.Value);
        else if (box.Value.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
            TakeObject((MyObject)box.Value);
    }
```

Makes the run times almost equal:

```
Without box: 00:00:07.9488281
With box: 00:00:08.6084029
```

Why? Because the JIT decides not to inline `IsDouble` and manual inlining helps. That is strange because it is such a small function. The `call` at line 13 is this call.

[image]

Now why is there still some performance difference? The .NET JIT is not the best compiler out there... there are probably some instructions a little bit different. You can find out by comparing the disassembly of the two versions. I'll not have time for that because I expect the difference to be quite uninsteresting.

I'd expect a C compiler to get this right. The struct should behave like the single `object` member that it contains. Small methods should be inlined. This is definitely doable with todays compiler technology. Let's hope that the next generation JIT and NGEN can do this. A new JIT is being developed at the moment (RyuJIT) and they're moving optimizations from the VC backend to NGEN (was recently announced).

Comment: Thank you for testing this. I didn't include how I run this. The results that I got was compiling using 32-bit (see edit). I've read about the JIT compilers and I know that the 32-bit and 64-bit compilers are different. I would still like to understand where the difference comes from that the 32-bit JIT compiler shows. What I'm trying to understand is why using a `struct` could be faster than an `object` under any circumstance.

Comment: With 32bit, the 2x difference is gone (probably it inlines). `Without box: 00:00:07.1796052
With box: 00:00:07.5055345` can't repro. With box is slower. Any idea why I cannot reproduce this? Without that I can't investigate further. Is this consistent for you when you run the program multiple times? Btw, your benchmark loop is very nice and clean. You even put warmup in. This is a clean benchmark. I'm on .NET 4.0.2.

Comment: What I did is: new console project in Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5; all default settings (this has the prefer 32-bit flag checked on my machine); replace the generated `Program.cs` with the provided sample and run. Try putting a `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)` around the `// The tests` thing and see if that changes your results.

Comment: I could reproduce this now with .NET 4.5. It looked to me like the JIT switched the order of the branches around in the WithBox case. I did not discover more, alas. The debugger is also behaving strangely. It is jumping on instructions that are not calls or branches... I give up. I think this is an accidental performance improvement. Using a struct seems to trigger an unrelated code change that happens to be slightly faster. This happens sometimes. For example, the JIT cannot know whether an if condition is likely to be taken or not. So it just guesses. Unrelated changes can flip the guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I'll wait a bit to see if I get other answers, but if I don't, I'll accept your answer.